# "0x0000006 The handle is invalid" error coming in multi-threaded environment

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, winapi, asmx, handle

I have created an ASP 3.5 web service which performs thumbnail generation using some Windows APIs. These APIs use Windows `HANDLE` or`HFILE` for processing. I am using Asynchronous AJAX in JavaScript to call the web-service.

- Server: ASP 3.5 Web Service
- Client: AJAX in JavaScript

When I am initiating only 1 request i.e. single thread in web service, no error is coming, but 
When I am initiating multiple requests i.e. multiple threads in web service, internal APIs listed below are giving errors randomly without any specific patterns. `GetLastError` returns error code `0x00000006`.

**Internal APIs:**
One Set

- `_llseek`
- `_lread`

Second Set

- `CreateFileMapping`
- `MapViewOfFile`

**Notes:**

- `_llseek` and `_lread` use `HANDLE` created using

  ```
  CreateFile(str, 0x80000000, 0x00000001, IntPtr.Zero, 3, 1, IntPtr.Zero)
  ```
- `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` use `HANDLE` created using,

  ```
  CreateFile(sThumbnailFile, (uint)(0x80000000 | 0x40000000), 0, IntPtr.Zero, 2, 128, IntPtr.Zero);
  ```

  no error or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` return code is coming while creating `HANDLE`.
- This issue is occurring randomly in multiple requests.
- Each `HANDLE`points to a different file.

I have even tested with `CRITICAL_SECTION` but issue still persists. Please suggest what could be the possible error?

Comment: Looks like a defect in your program. We cannot see it. Either debug this yourself, which you can do since you have the code. Or produce a [mcve].

Comment: By ASP 3.5 I assume you mean ASP.Net 3.5, removing [tag:asp-classic] tag as it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: What type of thumbnails? _llseek/_lread are depreciated are you calling them yourself?

Comment: Actually this `_llseek` is very old code used in a flat dll and that dll is being called using ASP.Net web service. I have also tried `SetFilePointer` but that is also failing. No variable or file is shared among different `HANDLE` but randomly error is coming.

Comment: Do you really think this it how it works? You ask us to guess what's wrong with your code? Make a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know solution would seem a little weird..but the problem was:
some other `HANDLE` in some other API was being closed improperly due to which these APIs started giving error at runtime in multi-threaded environment due to shortage of memory or other resource.

Thanks.